# How to add constraints to elements in a list for a Pydantic (V2) BaseModel?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have an object `Product` made from BaseModel. Its attribute `prices` is a `list` of `float`. I want to make sure that each element in the list must be a positive value.
I looked through the input parameters of `Field`, none of them is for this. The closest one is `gt` but it is only for `float` type not for `list[float]` type.

Could you please show me how to do it? Thanks.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Product(BaseModel):
    prices: list[float] = Field(
        max_length=3,
        min_length=2,
        gt=0,  # This one is not for list[float].
    )


p1 = Product(**{"prices": [1., -1.]})  # This should raise an error, since -1. < 0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pydantic.PositiveFloat` as the type in your list:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PositiveFloat


class Product(BaseModel):
    prices: list[PositiveFloat] = Field(
        max_length=3,
        min_length=2,
    )


p1 = Product(**{"prices": [1., -1.]})
# Raises 1 validation error for Product
# prices.1
#   Input should be greater than 0 [type=greater_than, input_value=-1.0, input_type=float]
```

See more at Pydantic Docs: [Number Types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/number_types/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works indeed. Do you have more general solution that allows to define a range, like 1.5<= element <=3.5?

Comment: @aura Yes. See the link I provided, specifically the section about the [`confloat`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.confloat) type constructor.